# Алгоритм оптимального раскроя линейных материалов

Tags: c++, алгоритм, php, delphi, javascript

Есть список заготовок с их длинами. Есть список деталей с их длинами, которые должны получиться из заготовок. Задача состоит в том, чтобы рассчитать наиболее оптимальное распределение деталей по заготовкам так, чтобы остатки получились минимальными.

Самое первое что приходит на ум - это банальный перебор всех возможных комбинаций и поиск минимальных отходов. Но, кол-во заготовок и кол-во деталей может быть довольно большим. А при переборе кол-во комбинаций будет расти в геометрической прогрессии.

Возможно кто сталкивался, существуют ли какие-то более эффективные решения, чем обычный перебор.

Comment: Насколько большим может быть количество? Мне кажется, тут при переборе довольно простая математика, можно им попробовать.

Comment: Ну полный-то перебор необязателен. Ветви и границы, кажись. Считать сумму отходов и при превышении ранее достигнутого минимума прекращать поиск по данной ветке прекращать -- решении будет не лучше ранее найденного.

Comment: @KiTE, кстати, если не секрет, это что-то универское-тестовое или такая задача в реальной жизни встала?)

Comment: Если память не изменяет Вам надо смотреть в сторону **"линейной алгебры"**. IMHO в 30-е годы за методы оптимизации раскроя фанеры некто Канторович получил Нобелевку.

--

Чуть ошибся. Нобелевка 1975, "Пионер и один из создателей линейного программирования." см. Википедия.

Comment: советую погуглить "np полные задачи", это даст вам базу для решения такого типа задач. имхо если вы не сталкивались с подобными раньше то решить ее будет сложно (даже разобратся, если вы конечно не гений-математики).  
на сколько мне известно есть 2 пути нахождения решения: 
1) полный перебор всех вариантов, - тогда наверняка удастся выбрать самый лучший (требует много времени)
2) частичный перебор вариантов, поиск продолжается до тех пор пока полученные результаты не будут отвечать критерия. напр.: у вас реальный выход заготовок из материала 80%, вас устроит любое решение проблемы где % выше

Comment: @mikillskegg, на самом деле ко-во не очень большое. Примерно 5-10 заготовок и 50-100 деталей. Вполне реально обычным перебором комбинаций. На данный момент я так и сделал. Перебираю возможные комбинации, пишу их в массив, затем выбираю наиболее экономную. Ну вот не чувствуется красоты решения :(. Хочется сделать более эффективный  алгоритм, чтобы потом его не стыдно было бы использовать где-либо :). А тут, при увеличении кол-ва вводных данных кол-во комбинаций растет геометрически и памяти для хранение комбинаций нужно много.

Comment: @Sh4dow, не секрет. Полностью жизненная ситуация. Знакомый по строительству занимается фигурной гибкой гипсокартона. И попросил сделать программу для расчета эффективного раскроя профиля.

Comment: @avp, спасибо за Канторовича!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта задача в англоязычной литературе носит название [**Cutting stock problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) и является одной из разновидностей *задачи о рюкзаке,* когда рюкзаков несколько.

---

Решать можно по-разному - динамическим программированием или приблизительными эвристиками.

Эвристическое решение вам, судя по всему, не подходит *(нужно точное решение)*, поэтому стоит смотреть в сторону [**динамики.**](http://people.orie.cornell.edu/~shmoys/or630/notes-06/lec16.pdf)

Comment: Большое спасибо за наводку! Буду разбираться и тренировать английский :)

Answer (score 0):

Задача непроста, но надо понимать, что сумма остатков заготовок при любом подборе заготовок к деталям в любом случае будет одинаковой.

**Дополнение:**

Ну, т.к по-любому придется иметь дело с каждым элементом массивов (заготовок и деталей),
то можно просто для каждой детали находить минимальный остаток, путем пробега по всем заготовкам и нахождения остатка для текущей детали. И так для каждой детали. Если же деталей слишком много(так много!), то почему бы вам просто не использовать такую прекрасную вещь, как потоки?

Comment: Это ещё с какого перепугу. Неверно

Comment: @alexz, с одной стороны он прав ( площадь деталей же от перестановки их не изменится, правильно?), с другой стороны, это не имеет отношения к задаче. Точнее, задача практически из этого исходит.

@Asen, имеется в виду расположение таким образом, чтобы детали были как можно кучнее и остаток был не кучей квадратов 1х1, а как можно бОльшим куском материала.

Comment: И блин, это комментарий, а не ответ `>_<`

Comment: Все ясно =)

Comment: @Sh4dow откуда взялись квадраты 1х1? В условиях задачи вроде ширины нет.

Comment: @alexlz, по ходу это я условие не понял =/ Почему-то подумал про лист материала и кучу заготовок, которые надо сделать из него. Прошу прощения)

Comment: @Asen, верно, сумма длин отходов в любом случае одинаковая. Но, видимо я не до конца раскрыл суть вопроса. Как верно отметил @Sh4dow, важно чтобы заготовки использовались как можно эффективнее. Нужно расположить детали по заготовке так, чтобы длинна остатка от каждой заготовки стремилась к нулю. А общая сумма всех отходов вылилась бы в один большой остаток от последней заготовки.

На счет потоков, верно, длительным расчетам именно там и место. Но это не проблема. Вопрос в алгоритме.