# Как нарезать палки, чтобы остался минимальный остаток?

Tags: javascript

Предположим у меня есть две палки длиной **200(см)**
Мне нужно получить много палок с длинами **40 30 35 30 40 25 55 40 90 5 (см)**

Если подбирать вручную то получится

```
30+30+40+40+55 = 195(см)
25+35+40+90+5 = 195(см)
Остаток: 5+5 = 10(см)
```

Хотелось бы иметь какой-то алгоритм, который бы минимизировал остаток (может есть что-то готовое, не могу понять что делать если палок много и остатков разных тоже много, перебирать?)

Comment: Нарезки фиксированы? Ограничены чем то или как то ?

Comment: у вас в списке доступных длин палое есть `5см` (самая последняя)... почему вы их в утиль списали? (в остаток)... вы ошиблись в решении или допустили ошибку в условии?

Comment: @МихаилРебров это не палки из списка - это отстаток от первого набора (200 - 195 = 5) и остаток от второго набора (200 - 195 = 5) при этом все длины были использованы по одному разу

Comment: @Grundy я вижу что это остаток. я к тому, что `5см` это приемлимая по условию длина для попадания в набор.

Comment: @Grundy `Мне нужно получить много палок с длинами 40/30/35/30/40/25/55/40/90/5 (см)` - последний вариант это 5 см. Значит она не должна идти в остаток.

Comment: тут же нет условия относительно того, что каждой палки должно быть по одной штуке... говориться ровно обратное: `Мне нужно получить много палок с длинами`. И у ТС в примере `40см` дублируется...тогда почему там не может быть двух по `5см`?

Comment: Это стандартная задача линейного раскроя.

Comment: @МихаилРебров, _тут же нет условия относительно того, что каждой палки должно быть по одной штуке_ - именно поэтому в списке значения дублируются :) посчитай общую сумму длин - она как раз и выйдет 390 - то есть в любом случае не хватило бы минимум тех же 10

Comment: @Akina, скорее о рюкзаке

Comment: @Grundy Нет, это одномерный раскрой. Задача о рюкзаке - это когда ещё и веса присутствуют. Хотя формально да - это можно считать и задачей о рюкзаке, в которой все весовые коэффициенты единичны. Но смысла нет - шаблонные способы решения рюкзака сложнее, чем одномерного раскроя.

Comment: @Akina, а, может быть :) постоянно их путаю :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Алгоритм оптимального раскроя линейных материалов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/81289/%d0%90%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: ещё дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/402815/178576) [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1323062/178576) [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1274797/178576) и т.д. и т.п.